# Converting ASP.NET MVC Standard application into N-Tier Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I was working on a application for which i was using **ASP.NET MVC**. Then i came to know about n-tier architecture which i think gives more  flexibility to the applications so i started *converting my standard mvc project into n-tier*. I also have role based views.
Before asking this question i've read many online articles about N-Tier architecture but everyone has it's own kinda n-tier structure. I didn't find any example which shows standarized structure of N-Tier application.
The MVC structure of my application was following :

```
Models :
- IBaseEntity
- IDeletableEntity
- IValidatableEntity
- File : IBaseEntity, IDeletableEntity, IvalidatableEntity
- User : IBaseEntitiy
Repositories :
- IRepo <T> where T : IBaseEntity
- IDeletableRepo <T> where T : IDeletableEntity
- IValidatableRepo <T> where T : IValidatableRepo
- Repo <T>: IRepo <T> where T : IBaseEntity
- DeletableRepo <T>: IDeletableRepo <T> where T : IDeletableEntity
- ValidatableRepo <T> : IValidatableRepo<T>where T : IValidatableRepo
- UnityOfWork //encapsulating all repos and providing acces to them
Services :
- IService <T>: where T : IBasEntity
- IValidatableService <T> where T : IValidatableEntity
- Service <T> : IService <T> : where T : IBasEntity
- ValidatableService <T>: IValidatableService <T> where T : IValidatableEntity

Controllers:
- FileController : Controller
- UserController : Controller

Views:
  File :
  - index.cshtml
  - view.cshtml
    Admin :
    - view.cshtml //Admin has more option while viewing page)
  User :
  - Profile.cshtml
    Admin :
    - AllProfile.cshtml
```

For converting it into N-Tier, i started reading so many online articles but i'm still confused. However i implemented n-tier come up with following structure :

```
Project Solution

 Project.BusinessObject
    Models

 Project.BusinessLogic
    Services

 Project.DataAccess
   Repositories

 Project.InversionOfControl
   Autofac

 Project.UserInterface
   Controllers
   ViewModels
   Views
```

The flow of my n-tier applications is : **Controllers -> Services -> Repoitory + AutoFac -> Models**
Actually i wanted post an image but i could'nt beacuse of 10 reputation criteria of stackoverflow. 
[You can click here to see n-tier structure of my application](http://postimg.org/image/pmyjop7kp/)
As it's my first experience with n-tier architecture i'm not sure if the application is well architectured or not. It'd be great help if someone can tell me about the points on which i was doing wrong or the points which need some kind of modification.

```
Some other questions if you could help me out :
Business object is same as a model ?
Business logics are methods for a business object ?
```

Comment: What you are doing is just layering the application. A "tier" means that the specific layer is running on an other physical machine. but that's not your question. There are a thousand of ways you can architecture an application. What i would advise is to limit the amount of layers and in your case combine the BussinessLogic and BussinessObject into one project since they belong together. And why are you using a separate project for your Ioc? Ioc is not a layer, it is a design pattern supporting construct. You can for example pull AutoFac in the projects that use it as a NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyH for the reponse, i will combine Business Logic and Business Object in a BusinessLayer Project as you mentionned above. Can i put AutoFac in Project.UserInterface or i've to put it somewhere else ?

Comment: Yes you can configure the AutoFac in the UI project. See http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/aspnet.html for Asp.Net documentation and examples. If your application grows over time and gets more complex and parts have to be reused you can use the AutoFac modules functionality: http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html but i would not start right away with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one that likes the tiered application approach for many reasons listed below. The MVC architecture is a tiered application. It means your application has:

A Presentation layer, the View,

An Application Processing Layer, the Controller, and

A Data Management Layer, the Model.

most developers use N-Tier application structure for a few different reasons.

1. to be able to run different parts of the application on different servers withing the intranet.
2. makes it easy to update one of the tiers without rewriting of the other tiers.
3. allows you to build additions to your application if properly built.

As for flexibility i find the n-tier's flexibility can be not so flexible, the idea is to separate your layers properly and have everything injected to the other layers, this can be a very cumbersome ordeal if you are new to creating such an application. If you are looking to separate your data from the application maybe make your Data Layer a web service. That way your MVC application will be able to access it, and so will your mobile application, your desktop application, or any other application that you wish to write.

In any event, multi-tier is primarily about scaling applications to multiple machines, as for flexibility i am not sure of anything you can do with N-tier that you cannot do with the MVC structure except for what i had listed.

There are a few good examples out there of a good n-tier architecture, Here are a few links.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/74633fdf-0563-4c75-aca8-f69835e7f8ab

http://www.orchardproject.net/

Comment: thans for the reponse, the links given really helped me out. As you mentionned in your answer,in future the data of the application will be  accessed from other plateforms as well (Mobile, tablets). So you think is it good to makeconvert  Data layer into a Web Service ? Would Web Services be secure as Data Access layer ?

Comment: This link may help you decide the best approach. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658127.aspx